# wine компас 3d v16.1

Tags: linux, wine

Установил все нужные библиотеки для компаса 3d, установил его, все ок вроде, только выскакивает сообщение что проблемы и нужно закрыть и не смотря на это все работает кроме, когда пытаюсь сохранить проект, как тут же ошибка и программа виснет.
устанавливал по: [установка](https://www.strangebot.ru/2018/06/3d-v161-hasp-linux.html).
вот лог ошибки:

```
    =================================================================
        Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a UNKNOWN while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
        Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
=================================================================
wine: Unhandled page fault on execute access to 0000000000000002 at address 0000000000000002 (thread 0110), starting debugger...
0160:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0x280be0, 1): stub
0160:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0000000000030A0E, 0000000000280BE0): stub
```

это что выводит в консоль.

Comment: В вашей инструкции при установке окружения уберите q и посмотрите как встает окружение. То что FrameWork 4.0 конфликтует с 4.5.2 это ерунда. Во первых 4.5.2 не кумулятивный это видно по размеру и он не будет работать без базы. Скрипт винных трюков ставит их оба по очереди. Запустите приложение в режиме отладки, смотрите в окне отладки на каком вызове WinAPI затык с этим проще работать чем дампы ковырять. Во всяком случае я так виндозамещался толку было больше все что мне было нужно я запустил.

Comment: @DmitryIvanov я изменил в вопросе лог, но я так ничего и не понял. Запускал с WINEDEBUG

Comment: Начните с экспериментов с mono. Он ругается не неизвестный вызов, значит в ему чего-то не хватает для работы. С mono вообще странная петрушка. Я когда ставил окружение в бутылке при первичной инициализации префикса выходит сообщение о необходимости установки mono и если согласится то ничего не работает, а если отказаться работает. На данный момент у меня нет объяснений по этому поводу

Comment: @DmitryIvanov Да запрос mono был, соглашался, устанавливало его. Вы предлагаете удалить его и затестить? Попробую

Comment: лучше пересоздать бутылку без него. Во всяком случае мое приложение на FrameWork 4.8 сборка x64 (да и x32) напрочь отказываются работать когда в бутылке есть mono. Базовая система Debian 11 со стоковым gnome. Все окружение я ставил через винные трюки.

Comment: @DmitryIvanov Попробовал без моно - не помогло, просто пишет что его нет. Теперь при сохранении такая ошибка: ```0110:fixme:commdlg:GetFileName95 Flags 0x00008000 not yet implemented
wine: Read access denied for device L"\\??\\Z:\\", FS volume label and serial are not available.
wine: Unhandled page fault on execute access to 0000000005811D80 at address 0000000005811D80 (thread 0110), starting debugger...
0158:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0x254b30, 1): stub
0158:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0000000000030A26, 0000000000254B30): stub``` ну дело явно не в пути, пробол сохранять в С:\

Comment: @ krolaper Read access denied for device L"\\??\\Z:\\" Эта проблема гуглится в чистом виде как мертвые или не допустимые ссылки (в запрещенное для непривилегированного пользователя расположение). Wine не должен работать под sudo и не может использоваться в программах требующих монопольный доступ к оборудованию типа Rufus. Я когда смотрел ваш пост думал что у вас будут проблемы с HASP но возможно это не так. Зы сегодня с содроганием обновился до 8 версии. Вроде все работает, но старые глюки остались. В том числе некорректная работа таймеров windows form.